# Python command line with quotes

Tags: command-line

I need to send this string from Python app to command line:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit
> PhantomPDF\FoxitPhantomPDF.exe" "C:\SPC\Pdf_SPC\file.pdf"

when I copy it directly to command line, it works, when I send it:

```
os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit PhantomPDF\FoxitPhantomPDF.exe" "C:\SPC\Pdf_SPC\file.pdf")
```

it doesn't work

but this works:

```
os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit PhantomPDF\FoxitPhantomPDF.exe")
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks